# How to indicate change of order in the one tuple when comparing two tuples in python?

Tags: python, tuples

I am facing a problem with comparing following tuples:

```
chains = ['A','B','C','D']
proper_list = ['ABBA','BDDA','CDDA','ABBA']
corrupted_list = ['ABBA','CDDA','BDDA','ABBA']

proper_set = tuple(zip(chains, proper_list))
corrupted_set = tuple(zip(chains, corrupted_list))
```

The output of both is as follows:

```
(('A', 'ABBA'), ('B', 'BDDA'), ('C', 'CDDA'), ('D', 'ABBA')),
(('A', 'ABBA'), ('B', 'CDDA'), ('C', 'BDDA'), ('D', 'ABBA'))
```

I would like to somehow print out the updated tuple, where an algorithm could find and indicate improper element assigned to value, as follows:

```
(('A', 'ABBA'), ('C', 'CDDA'), ('B', 'BDDA'), ('D', 'ABBA'))
```

or at least yield the list with proper order:

```
['A','C','B','D']
```

As the elements in proper/corrupted lists may  be duplicated I cannot (or am not able to) use dict.

Assumptions:

- lengths of both lists and elements will always be equal
- the order of any element in corrputed_list may differ

What could you suggest to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you explain the logic behind: `(('A', 'ABBA'), ('C', 'CDDA'), ('B', 'BDDA'), ('D', 'ABBA'))` ?

Comment: What is the *proper order*?

Comment: @JonClements In fact, chains stands for list of chains present in protein sequence, where 'proper list' is a representation of sequences present in protein. It is like: 
Chain A has a sequence of ADDA
Chain B has a sequence of BDDA 
Chain C has a sequence of CDDA
Chain D has a sequence of ABBA (identical to A)

In the generated file (that yields corrupted_set), algorithm incorrectly assigns chains B and C:
B: CDDA
C: BDDA

Logic is: I need to find where it failed and print properly-ordered list of chains in generated file

Comment: make your custom tuple subclass and implement `__eq__` as desired

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to understand your question but this seems to get the result you want:

```
chains = ['A','B','C','D']
proper_list = ['ABBA','BDDA','CDDA','ABBA']
corrupted_list = ['ABBA','CDDA','BDDA','ABBA']

proper_set = tuple(zip(chains, proper_list))
corrupted_set = tuple(zip(chains, corrupted_list))

result = ()
result_indexes = []

def idxExluded(val, ex):
    for i in range(len(corrupted_list)):
        if (corrupted_list[i] == val and (i not in ex)):
            return i
    return -1

for s in proper_set:
    key = s[0]
    val = s[1]
    for cor_set in corrupted_set:
        if (cor_set[0] == key and cor_set[1] == val):
            result = result + ((key, val), )
            result_indexes.append(idxExluded(val, result_indexes))
            break
        if (cor_set[1] == val):
            result = result + ((key, val), )
            result_indexes.append(idxExluded(val, result_indexes))
            break;

print(result) # Mapped result
# (('A', 'ABBA'), ('B', 'BDDA'), ('C', 'CDDA'), ('D', 'ABBA'))


def mapIdxs(val):
    return result_indexes[result.index(val)]
    
result_sorted = list(result)
result_sorted.sort(key=mapIdxs)
result_sorted = tuple(result_sorted)

print(result_sorted) # Sorted mapped result
# (('A', 'ABBA'), ('C', 'CDDA'), ('B', 'BDDA'), ('D', 'ABBA'))
```

Obvisouly it is not optimised nor using any builtin functions, I just did a quick POC

Comment: It still yields: (('A', 'ABBA'), ('B', 'BDDA'), ('C', 'CDDA'), ('D', 'ABBA'))

And as I mentioned, I'd like to get:

(('A', 'ABBA'), ('C', 'CDDA'), ('B', 'BDDA'), ('D', 'ABBA'))

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to fix the chain in case it has an issue using the sequence so something like this

```
chains = ['A','B','C','D']
proper_list = ['ABBA','BDDA','CDDA','ABBA']
corrupted_list = ['ABBA','CDDA','BDDA','ABBA']

proper_set = tuple(zip(chains, proper_list))
corrupted_set = tuple(zip(chains, corrupted_list))

result = []

for x,y in corrupted_set:
    if (x,y) in proper_set:
        # if the current tuple is actually a proper tuple just append it
        result.append((x,y))
    else:
        # if it's not a proper tuple we need to fix the chain so find the sequence in the proper list then pick the correspoding chain
        i = proper_list.index(y)
        result.append((chains[i],y))

print(result)
```